# Locator fails randomly with Selenium and ChromeDriver in headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have a drop down menu which has the text "My Menu". Unfortunately the same drop down is used for another purpose with the text "My Second Menu". I need to click on this "My Menu" drop down and it looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="c-composedDropdown u-display--flex u-align-items--center u-color--white u-cursor--pointer u-border-radius">
  <div class="u-display--flex u-align-items--center">
     <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-lg flag-icon-ie composedDropdown__subTitle__icon u-color--white" />
     <div>
        <div class="u-display--block u-display--flex u-align-items--center">
           <span class="u-font-weight--bold u-margin-right--medium">My Menu</span>
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" baseProfile="tiny" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" color="#37454D" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="c-composedDropdown__arrow-icon u-color--blue-lighter">
              <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M9.5 7l5 5m-5 5l5-5" class="svg-color--primary" />
           </svg>
        </div>
        <p class="c-composedDropdown__subTitle u-display--block">Sample</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

At the moment, I'm using XPath to capture this and it looks like the following.

```
//*[contains(@class, 'c-composedDropdown') and contains (.,'My Menu')]
```

The test scenario for this passes fine whenever I run it alone. But when the entire test suite runs, randomly this test fails. That too when running in headless mode. Is there something I can do about the way I pick this element to be clicked? Will that help the test not so flaky? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with formatted text based relevant HTML.

Comment: @KunduK I've updated the question with the text based HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try following Xpath Hope this will work.

```
//div[contains(@class,"c-composedDropdown")]//following-sibling::span[text()="My Menu"]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity as I'm still learning deep about XPaths, how would this help with the flakiness of the test at the moment? :)

Comment: @mayooran : Not sure though whether it will work in headless mode.Try with interactive mode first check whether it works.if works then try in headless mode.Let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **My Menu** you need to induce to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  "div.c-composedDropdown span.u-font-weight--bold.u-margin-right--medium"
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  "//div[contains(@class, 'c-composedDropdown')]//span[@class='u-font-weight--bold u-margin-right--medium' and text()='My Menu']"
  ```

Comment: I cannot use the above CSS selector as there's also another drop down with the same properties but has a different text "My Second Menu" as I've mentioned in the question :)

Comment: @mayooran If you can update the question with both the similar _DropDown_ nodes possibly we can workout for an effective _CssSelector_ as well. Can you update about 
 the result using the _xpath_ within my answer?

Comment: XPath seems to be incorrect, gives me an unable to locate the element all the time :(

Comment: Possibly you haven't added the much needed **WebDriverWait** which would be crucial for your usecase.